# Как измененить цвет одного из группы объектов с общим материалом?

Tags: unity3d

Есть 10 кубов. На каждый повесил один и тот же материал. 
Есть ли возможность изменять цвет отдельного куба?
Сейчас изменяется цвет материала и перекрашиваются все кубы. 
Цвет будет задаваться из кода и я не знаю какие цвета будут использоваться, так что создать 10 материалов с разными цветами - не вариант.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Если не затрагивать вопрос GPU instancing`а, то только создавая новый материал во время рантайма.**

Вы, вероятно, знакомы со свойствами `Renderer.sharedMaterial` и `Renderer.material`.

Первый вариант возвращает **общий** для группы объектов материал, изменение которого ведет к изменению отрисовки всей группы объектов - материал то общий.

> The shared material of this object.
>
> Modifying sharedMaterial will change the appearance of all objects
>   using this material, and change material settings that are stored in
>   the project too.
>
> It is not recommended to modify materials returned by sharedMaterial.
>   If you want to **modify the material** of a renderer **use material** instead.

Второй вариант тоже может вернуть общий материал, но разница в том, что при его изменении создается копия материала.

> Returns the first instantiated Material assigned to the renderer.
>
> Modifying material will **change the material** for **this object only**.
>
> **If** the material is **used by** any **other renderers**, this **will clone the**
>   **shared material** and start using it from now on.

```
// скопирует существующий материал и поменяет его цвет
GetComponent<Renderer>().material.SetColor("_Color", Color.black);
```

---

Будьте внимательны - порождение новых материалов с помощью такого способа может "выйти из под контроля" в плане количества копий. Более того, может возникнуть ситуация, при которой вы создадите 2 разных материала с одинаковыми свойствами.

Выхода тут 2:

1. Лучше заведите какой-то менеджер, который будет следить за тем, какие материалы и в каком количестве вы создаете, что позволит не создавать лишние копии.
2. Используйте GPU instancing и Property Block`и.